# The difference between fight for and fight against

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I wrote a paper about whether online privacy should be regulated by laws.
My point is that laws cannot set universal rules to regulate online personal information, but laws can help people prevent their personal information from being eroded by gaining more knowledge. So should I say "people fight for battle of online privacy" or "fight against"?
My instructor commented that I should write "for" while I used "against" all the time. So can anyone tell me the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

You rarely fight *for* or *against* a battle, unless it has not yet happened and you think you can affect whether it happens or not.

Instead you "fight a battle" or "fight in a battle"

Answer (score 1):

You fight *for* what is dear to you and fight *against* what threatens you.

You could dispense with "battle" and write "people *fight for* their online privacy".

Alternatively, "people *fight against* erosion of their personal privacy".